# Storyboards landscape mode with Trait collections

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uistoryboard, uitraitcollection

I have an app that only works in Landscape mode and am using storyboard to layout views. The problem is using Trait collections/size classes the view is by default shown in portrait mode that makes it difficult to layout.  I am unable to find anyway to change the frame of main UIView so that it shows in landscape. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 8, you can select the orientation of the view controllers in the storyboard by clicking the device family and size class button on the bottom of the Interface Builder screen when you have the Storyboard open.

Device family and size classes button

[image: [1]]

---

This exposes the device configuration pane in which you can select different screen sizes and orientation.

Device configuration pane

[image: [2]]